# I regularly receive a no such host message but my application is working

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, authentication

So my sign up/log in system is working but from time to time I get this exception message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 6 limit 1)
```

Why do I get it when my application is working?

Comment: DNS server failed to resolve the database host ip from the hostname. Depending on your DNS configuration it may happen occasionally. It may also happen when the host is actually down temporarily.

Comment: How I can fix this? Is not really satisfying seeing it from time to time.

Comment: Well first thing to try is to use the database IP instead of the hostname in your database configuration and see if that helps. If not then double-check to make sure your database does not get restarted from time to time . Amazon for example will occasionally restart databases hosted in RDS to install security updates and that's normal.